# does anyone know a nice form of the infinite sum $\sum_{n=0, m=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^n b^m}{(n+m)!}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I was wondering if anyone on here knows of a closed form or special function for this infinite sum:

$$\sum_{n=0, m=0}^{\infty} \frac{a^n b^m}{(n+m)!}$$

Or the sum of any non-trivial subset.

Answer (score 11):

Letting $p=n+m$ this is:

$$\sum_{p=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{p!}\sum_{n=0}^{p} a^nb^{p-n}$$

But $$\sum_{n=0}^{p} a^nb^{p-n}=\frac{a^{p+1}-b^{p+1}}{a-b}$$

So your sum is:

$$\frac{1}{a-b}\sum_{p=0}^\infty \frac{a^{p+1}-b^{p+1}}{p!} = \frac{ae^a-be^b}{a-b}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Leftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\, #2 \,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\sum_{n = 0,m = 0}^{\infty}{a^{n}b^{m}\over \pars{n + m}!}} & =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a^{n}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}{b^{m}\over \pars{n + m}!} =
\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}a^{n}b^{-n}\sum_{m = n}^{\infty}{b^{m}\over m!} =
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}{b^{m}\over m!}\sum_{n = 0}^{m}\pars{{a \over b}}^{n}
\\[3mm] & = 
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}{b^{m}\over m!}{\pars{a/b}^{m + 1} - 1 \over a/b - 1} =
{b \over a - b}\pars{{a \over b}\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}{a^{m} \over m!} -
\sum_{m = 0}^{\infty}{b^{m} \over m!}}
\\[3mm] & =
{b \over a - b}\pars{{a \over b}\,\expo{a} - \expo{b}} =
\color{#f00}{{a\expo{a} - b\expo{b} \over a - b}}
\end{align}